# Hydrogen isotope effect on methyl shift

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, hydrocarbons, carbocation, rearrangements

Consider this typical 1,2 methanide shift in a carbocation:

[image]

Which isotopic form of methanide ($\ce{CH3, CD3, or CT3}$) would migrate from secondary carbocation to form more stable tertiary carbocation?

[This](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02969505#:%7E:text=1%2C2%2Delectron%2Ddeficient,group%20is%20a%20negative%20ion.) link explains the mechanism but I could not understand the abstract.

Assuming that the migration of $\ce{CH3-}$ takes place, the following facts can be considered:

- The electronegativity of $\ce{CH3}$ is highest, thus, the formation of $\ce{CH3->CH3-}$ (methanide) is easiest. Consequently, the migration would be fastest in this case.
- The transition state would be most unstable in this case due to highest electronegativity of $\ce{CH3}$.
- The tertiary carbocation would be most stable in this case due to order of $\mathrm{+I}$ effect: $\ce{CT3 > CD3 > CH3}$

There are few exchanged comments below the second answer of [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102088/why-is-d3-acetic-acid-more-acidic-than-acetic-acid/127659?noredirect=1#comment279210_127659) question and the proper explanation can be found in [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja50001a040) link, which I can't access.

Comment: @Safdar So, the stability of T.S. is more important than that of final carbocation. In your comment, the numerator and denominator are same.